# Node JS & MongoDB - Post and Get images for iOS server api

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, mongodb

I am doing a very basic server for an app I am working on to help me understand node js and mongodb as a server for my mobile app. I have followed a tutorial and got it working posting simple todos. But what I want to do next is post images along with the text in the POST request and retrieve them with the GET request as JSON. Below is the code that I have so far which successfully posts the todo name along with the created at date to the db.

The below class is what I had for the Schema but I attempted to add how I thought an image would be added, but I do not think this is correct. I believe the correct practice would be to store the images in a file system for example `https://{mydomain}/images/` and then when posting the image data, store the image in the folder and the url to the image in the database?

todoListModel.js

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var TaskSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
  },
  img: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  },
  Created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

todoListController.js

```
'use strict';


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({
      data: {
        task
      }
    });
  });
};




exports.create_a_task = function(req, res) {
  var new_task = new Task(req.body);
  new_task.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({
      data: {
        task
      }
    });
  });
};


exports.read_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({
      data: {
        task
      }
    });
  });
};


exports.update_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({
      data: {
        task
      }
    });
  });
};


exports.delete_a_task = function(req, res) {


  Task.remove({
    _id: req.params.taskId
  }, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'Task successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

todoListRoutes.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var todoList = require('../controllers/todoListController');

  // todoList Routes
  app.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);


  app.route('/tasks/:taskId')
    .get(todoList.read_a_task)
    .put(todoList.update_a_task)
    .delete(todoList.delete_a_task);
};
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = require('./api/models/todoListModel'), //created model loading here
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var routes = require('./api/routes/todoListRoutes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route


app.listen(port);


console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

If someone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be the best approach first upload the image into your project folder or you can upload the image in AWS S3 bucket if you are using, and then store the path of that image into your collection.
Correct schema would be

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
 },
 img: {
  type: String,
 },
 Created_date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 }
});
```

Comment: Does this mean that I need to save the image with a unique name to the folder in the post request and then when it is saved, put the image URL in the database once it is saved? If so do you have a sample as to how this would be done?

Comment: Refer this http://blog.robertonodi.me/simple-image-upload-with-express for uploading image in expressjs.

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/hawksaggs/image_upload i made naive social networking wesite type project